# Change webview to landscape when specific webpage is requested

Tags: java, android-studio, webview

I want to have the phone screen change to landscape mode when a particular page is loaded in webview. My code is not working. There are no errors. It's just simply not changing into landscape mode when the particular page is loaded in webview. Is there something I forgot or am I doing incorrectly. I don't want to force landscape when webview is loaded as there are other web pages that are used that need to be shown in portrait. Maybe possibly I forgot something else? I'm stuck.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if( url.startsWith("http:")) {
        return false;
    }

    //CHANGE INTO LANDSCAPE FOR SIGNATURE
    if( url.contains("get-signature.php")) {
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        return true;
    }


    if(url.contains("https://www.google.com/maps/")) {
        Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
        if (mapIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(mapIntent);
        }
        return true;
    }


    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity( intent );
    return true;
}

});
```